How to catch if-then (and optional else) block from rsyslog config file?
I'd like to catch the following conditional blocks from rsyslog conf file:
if (($fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1') and ($syslogfacility-text == "local7")) then {
        if (re_match($msg, "^[ ]*[A-Z0-9]{4}\\|[^|]+\\|")) then {
                action(type="omfile" DynaFile="a_DynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
        } else {
                action(type="omfile" DynaFile="b_malformedDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
        }
}

if (($fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1') and ($syslogfacility-text == "local6")) then {
    action(type="omfile" DynaFile="qradarDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
} 
else { action(type="omfile" DynaFile="b_malformedDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on") }

I'l trying to catch the body of condition (($fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1') and ($syslogfacility-text == "local7")) from the first block and entire body ignoring nested blocks :
        if (re_match($msg, "^[ ]*[A-Z0-9]{4}\\|[^|]+\\|")) then {
                action(type="omfile" DynaFile="a_DynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
        } else {
                action(type="omfile" DynaFile="b_malformedDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
        }

And if occured also the else block but only from the main 1st level, so for the 2nd example get all three groups:

(($fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1') and ($syslogfacility-text == "local6"))
action(type="omfile" DynaFile="qradarDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
action(type="omfile" DynaFile="b_malformedDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")

I'm trying to get it with pattern if([^}]*)|then([^}]*)|else([^}]*) but it seems to be too general and stops on first curly bracket in the then body

Using regex for this seems futile. You want a proper parser for this format.

I dont actually know if you want this result but try this:
import re

reg = re.compile(r'(^(?P<cond>(if|el)(?P<else>se)?(?(else) |(.+) then))\s*\{(?![\r\n\s]+if)[\r\n\s]+(?P<nested>[\s\S]+?)[\r\n\s]+\})|(^(?P<cond2>if.+) then\s*\{[\r\n\s]+if)', flags=8)

example = '''if (($fromhost-ip == \'127.0.0.1\') and ($syslogfacility-text == "local7")) then {
        if (re_match($msg, "^[ ]*[A-Z0-9]{4}\\|[^|]+\\|")) then {
                action(type="omfile" DynaFile="a_DynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
        } else {
                action(type="omfile" DynaFile="b_malformedDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
        }
}

if (($fromhost-ip == \'127.0.0.1\') and ($syslogfacility-text == "local6")) then {
    action(type="omfile" DynaFile="qradarDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on")
} 
else { action(type="omfile" DynaFile="b_malformedDynFile" dynaFileCacheSize="128" fileCreateMode="0644" dirCreateMode="0755" dirGroup="log" fileGroup="log" asyncWriting="on") }'''

for matching in reg.finditer(example):
    print('cond1:', matching['cond'])
    print('cond2:', matching['cond2'])
    print('nested:', matching['nested'])

